# Turn 4 Switches into Dimmers on 1 Plate

Tags: lighting, dimmer-switch

I have an open floor plan living/ dining/ kitchen area with recessed kitchen lights, a pendant over the dining table, pendant lights over the sink and recessed living room lights and the switches are all on one plate. Only the pendants over the dining table have a dimmer.
I want to change them from them to each be on a dimmer of their own.
Can i do this if so how do i do this?
thank you.

Comment: do they all have separate switch

Comment: What type of light bulbs are they?  Some LEDs do not like dimmers.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the switch box without the plate?

Comment: Yes, can you please post photos of the inside of the switch box in question?